# Sessions limited on server?

Tags: php, session, opencart

```
2011-12-08 17:24:04 - PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

2011-12-08 17:24:04 - PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
```

Getting these errors after uploading a certain amount of content.  Also, noticed that can no longer log in to admin panel. Could this be cause by too many sessions be stored on a server?  Or anyone have any other ideas?  First happened after uploading a few images through admin panel in open cart.

I am hosting a bunch of sites off of one server.  SO it seems likely but has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks very likely that you've run out of space on the disk and so causing many things to fail. Try freeing up some space and try again.

Comment: in the process of confirming with hosting company.

Comment: ya, dreamhost just messed up and had limited size for our account.  those bastards.

Comment: To be honest, at the very least you should be on a VPS to control your server settings that much more if using an e-commerce platform